# Spring MVC : Unable to get json value in jsp, it's giving 0

Tags: java, json, jsp, spring-mvc, modelandview

Need your help. I am not able to get json string in jsp after adding in modelAndView. After debugging, I found it's get added in modelAndView instace.

Below is the code snippet:

**Controller:**

```
modelAndView.addObject("json-data",jsonhelper.getJSONString(viewData));
```

**JSP**

```
<c:if test="${json-data != null}">

<script type="text/javascript">

     window.jsonData =${json-data};

 </script>

</c:if>
```

Here viewData is the object, that I need to get in jsp, but in jsp it's giving 0.

Comment: So how does javascript understand what your java code is?

Comment: Is it getting printed in your controller?

Comment: can you try this code in your jsp `<script type="text/javascript">var jsonStr = <c:out value="${json}"/>; alert(jsonStr);</script>`

Comment: @NamanGala, yes it is printed in controller.

Comment: @NamanGala, when I try to alert json string, it gives 0.

Comment: Just trying to cross check, are you printing `jsonhelper.getJSONString(viewData)` or `viewData` in your controller?

Comment: Did you see any errors on the server logs ?
Did you try Bewusstsein's suggestion ?

Comment: Yes I tried, it's working perfectly. No error logs. Bu ti want to know complete info about that, what else other rules should follow to avoid this kind of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash (`-`) in `json-data` is being interpreted as the arithmetic operator `minus`.

According to the [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf) (1.7.1):

> Binary operators - A {+,-,*} B
>
> If A and B are null, return (Long)0

Therefore `json-data` is resolved to `0`, `json-data != null` yields true, and `window.jsonData` is assigned the value `0`.

One solution is to rename your variable to `jsonData` or any other valid Java identifier.

Alternatively, this will also work:

```
window.jsonData = <%= request.getAttribute("json-data") %>
```

Comment: I got that, but is it mentioned somewhere in documentation

Comment: @ved I looked and found that my first answer wasnt quite correct, see edited answer for clarification and reference to the EL spec.

Comment: link you have mentioned is not working. Please give me valid link.

Comment: @ved the link should work now; if not, try this one: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/7045154/UEL.pdf or search for "jsp expression language specification type:pdf"